# Creating a UITabBar With a Normal UIViewController(Not UITabBarController)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIViewController and I wish to place a simple UITabBar like the in the screenshot below: I don't want to use an UITabBarController. In fact, my original setup uses one, and it's easy as cake to get it to work.

However, the thing is I found out it's a bad idea to put UITabBarControllers inside Navigation Controllers, so I'm forced to refactor the hierarchy (so please don't suggest using one).

Given an UIViewController, how can I add an UITabBar on the bottom programatically? I got my UITabBarDelegate all setup to show a specific view when 1 of the tab bars is clicked, but the problem is when the view controller loads, no tab bar shows up! Here's my code to do that:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
        ...some initialization...
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 431, 320, 49);


    profileItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
    profileItem.image = icon;
    profileItem.title = @"Diet";    

    tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    NSArray* items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:profileItem, nil];

    tabBar.items = items;
    tabBar.delegate = self;
    [tabBar setSelectedItem:[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]];

    [self.view addSubview:tabBar];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

What am I missing here?

[image]

**EDIT**: Argh, I found out it has to do with the frame... Hmm.. what y-coordinate should I use if I have an existing navigation header on top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention in your edit that you already determined that it has to do with the frame.  Your problem may stem from the fact that your view's size in `viewDidLoad` isn't guaranteed to be the same is it will be when it eventually gets displayed.  UIKit resizes the view to fit the context in which it's being displayed just before `viewWillAppear:`.

If you want to add the tab bar in `viewDidLoad`, then you should position it at the bottom of your view's frame by doing some math:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 49,
                          self.view.bounds.size.width, 49);
```

Then set an appropriate autoresizingMask so that it remains at the bottom even if UIKit resizes your view:

```
tabBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```